# How can I let the Tkinter GUI not replace a string?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I was writing a code in Python (with Tkinter), and I couldn't fix a little problem. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
    straal = int(e1.get())
    area = 3.143 * (straal * straal)
    area_label['text'] = str(area)

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Straal").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

area_label = Label(master, text="Oppervlakte")
area_label.grid(row=2)

Button(master, text='Sluit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Bereken oppervlakte', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

When I run the program, then it does work, but if it calculates the area, then the text 'oppervlakte' gets replaced by the answer. Before you calculate:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOgRR.jpg

After you calculate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLKil.jpg

How can I let the GUI display:

Oppervlakte: 78.5749999999

Thanks in advance

Comment: please include the images in your post rather than links =)

Comment: i think you are replacing your label in the function you have:  area_label['text'] = str(area) instead of creating a new label

Comment: @glls yeah I tried but I needed +10 reputation

Comment: remember to accept the answer you used as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing your label in the function you have: area_label['text'] = str(area) instead of creating a new label, create a new label with no text and then populate it in your function:

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
    straal = int(e1.get())
    area = 3.143 * (straal * straal)
    calculation_label['text'] = str(area)    #using new label

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Straal").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

area_label = Label(master, text="Oppervlakte")
area_label.grid(row=2)
calculation_label = Label(master, text="")    #new label
calculation_label.grid(row=2, column=1)

Button(master, text='Sluit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Bereken oppervlakte', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer I need. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: please consider up-voting the answers provided to you. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could change this:

```
area_label['text'] = str(area)
```

to this:

```
area_label['text'] = "Oppervlakte: {}".format(area)
```

If you don't want to duplicate the "Oppervlakte" text, you'll need to create two labels, one for "Oppervlakte" and another one (perhaps initially empty) to hold the actual number.

Comment: Yeah it kind of works but then the `straal` with the input does move really far to the right

Comment: @L.Peters: Then you need to rethink your layout.  In your layout, you only have two labels and one input, so that's all it's going to leave room for.  If you want something else, you need to do as I suggested in the second part of my answer and add a second label with appropriate placing in the GUI.